# ArcGIS Spatial Join Options Missing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, spatial-join, error-000800

The ArcGIS [SpatialJoin online help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) has a long list of match_options when joining data spatially, including HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN.

However running the arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis tool in Python with this option results in an error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of INTERSECT | CONTAINS | WITHIN | CLOSEST.
Failed to execute (SpatialJoin).
```

These options are also missing from ArcToolBox:

[image]

The licensing on the help page suggests this tool is available for all versions of ArcGIS:

> ArcView: Yes ArcEditor: Yes ArcInfo: Yes

So is this an error in the docs, licensing on keywords, or a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: Just looked in my version of ArcGIS 10 (SP3).  I have an ArcEditor Licence on the machine I'm using at the moment and I _DO_ have the HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN in option in ArcToolBox.  So, this isn't an answer, but it does prove that it is NOT a misunderstanding of the documentation on your part and that something else must be awry.  It wouldn't be a Service Pack issue would it?

Comment: Can you post your script? Maybe you have your parameters out of order. The Match Option should be the 7th argument. "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN" is a valid match option.

Comment: @klewis - I tried both with named arguments, and the full 7 parameters - same result. The error message indicates it is the correct parameter, but not a valid option.

Comment: @sylvester - will look at updating service packs, I fear it is a license limitation (using ArcView at the moment)

Comment: Using ArcGIS 10 SP3, I see a "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN" with the **ArcView** license level and when I run it I don't get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [list of fixes in SP3](http://downloads.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/10.0_SP3_Announcement.pdf) it appears it was an error and has been fixed:

> NIM070795 - Spatial Join tool not ignoring invalid match options.

I installed the service pack, and now all options are present in the ArcToolbox tool, and my script runs without problems.

Thanks to @sylvester for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been asked with ERROR 000800 before and it looks like it wasn't a licensing error then.
The previous question - [ERROR 000800 when trying to snap points layer to line or buffer layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16376/error-000800-when-trying-to-snap-points-layer-to-line-or-buffer-layer) - so the problem is most likely an error with your script though you'll have to give us more specifics of the script if you want specific feedback.

There's also a ESRI thread here: [The value is not a member of %s](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1734&t=273684)