# Perform a spatial join in C# with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I feel like this has to be on the internet somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it.

**I'm attempting** to perform a spatial join on a polygon and point layer.  My goal is to push the polygon's ID to each point that it contains.  In PostGIS, it might look close to this:  `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a, b WHERE ST_CONTAINS(a, b)`.

**I have:**

1. A polygon IFeatureClass, from a geodatabase
2. A point IFeatureClass, from a geodatabase
3. The name of the polygon field

I would like to turn this into a point IFeatureClass with an extra field.

**My question:** How do I do this?  Bonus points for links to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do it with the Geoprocessor in ArcObjects like this:

```
public static void SpatialJoiner(IFeatureClass sourceFC, IFeatureClass joinFC)
{
    Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();
    ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.SpatialJoin spatialJoin = new ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools.SpatialJoin();
    spatialJoin.join_features = joinFC;
    spatialJoin.target_features = sourceFC;
    spatialJoin.join_type = "KEEP_COMMON";
    spatialJoin.match_option = "WITHIN";
    spatialJoin.fieldmapping = fieldMapping;
    spatialJoin.out_feature_class = @"c:\yourPath\your.gdb\outfile";
    GP.Execute(spatialJoin,null);
}
```

Spatial Join class documentation: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/00470000328n000000/

Note that the "fieldmMapping" object needs to be constructed and populated with the IGPFieldMapping interface:

```
IGPFieldMapping fieldMapping = new GPFieldMappingClass();
```

Field Mapping Documentation: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004800000194000000

Comment: If you're curious about the `match_option` values available, check [this page (10.0)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) or [this page (10.1)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000). The docs linked in the answer [didn't elaborate deeply](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/match_option_Property/004700003q70000000/) on the `match_option`. Thanks to [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24510/arcgis-spatial-join-options-missing) for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to do this through the geoprocessor.

You can run [geoprocessing tools from ArcObjects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/0001/0001000003rr000000.htm) using these general steps:

> 1. Add a reference to ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing to your project. This is the only reference you need if you use the geoprocessing assembly.
> 2. Create the geoprocessor object.
> 3. Add the path to the custom toolbox if you are running a custom tool.
> 4. Create an IVariantArray and populate it with tool parameter values. The IVariantArray is available through the esriSystem library.
> 5. Call the Execute method on the geoprocessor.