# Snapping points to line yields error 000800?

Tags: arcpy, snapping, error-000800

I am trying to snap points (temp2.shp) to nearest line (Rail2.shp) at any of its vertex within any distance.

ArcPy code:

```
temp2 = "M:\\temp2.shp"
arcpy.Snap_edit(temp2, ["M:\\Rail2", "VERTEX", '10000 Feet'])
```

Error Message:

```
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of END | VERTEX | EDGE.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of END | VERTEX | EDGE.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of END | VERTEX | EDGE.
Failed to execute (Snap).
```

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/16627/64080) to [ERROR 000800 when trying to snap points layer to line or buffer layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/16376/115) helped.

Adding a set of square brackets on top of the existing square brackets.

Working code:

```
temp2 = "M:\\temp2.shp"
arcpy.Snap_edit(temp2, [["M:\\Rail2", "VERTEX", '10000 Feet']])
```